# "VMware Player does not support nested virtualization on this host" with Hyper-V off

Tags: cmd.exe, vmware, hypervisor

I can't run a virtual machine I need for an IOS development. It was working in the past on the same machine, I think -from the comment I read here and there- that this is because I used WSL that uses Hyper-V.
So I disabled Hyper-V but I still have that error, when I try to run the virtual machine in VMWare:

```
Error while powering on: VMware Player does not support nested virtualization on this host.

Module 'MonitorMode' power on failed.

Failed to start the virtual machine.
```

I also tried all the command lines in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line) so don't mark mine as a duplicate.

Comment: In order to properly answer this question, you must provide what version of VMWare Player you are using and what version of Windows 10 you are running.  The current version VMWare Player is fully compatible with Hyper-V but only if your running the current version of Windows 10.  Additionally, WSL 2 doesn’t require Hyper-V to be enabled, it’s not necessary (an entirely different optional Windows Feature is required). Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 2):

Do you have WSL enabled? You might need to disable it separately. The following cmdlet should help.

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

You can check the following article to get more info about nested virtualization.
https://www.vmwareblog.org/nested-virtualization-vmware-esxi-vs-microsoft-hyper-v/

Comment: WSL1 doesn't use a VM at all. Only wsl2 runs in a VM

Comment: @phuclv - WSL2 doesn’t actually require Hyper-V to be installed.